# Vector + for + if

Tags: c++, if-statement, for-loop, vector, addition

OK, so the goal of this was to write some code for the Fibonacci numbers itself then take those numbers figure out which ones were even then add those specific numbers together. Everything works except I tried and tried to figure out a way to add the numbers up, but I always get errors and am stumped as of how to add them together. I looked elsewhere but they were all asking for all the elements in the vector. Not specific ones drawn out of an if statement.

P.S. I know system("pause") is bad but i tried a few other options but sometimes they work and sometimes they don't and I am not sure why. Such as cin.get().

P.S.S I am also new to programming my own stuff so I have limited resources as far as what I know already and will appreciate any ways of how I might "improve" my program to make it work more fluently. I also take criticism well so please do.

```
#include "../../std_lib_facilities.h"

int main(){
    vector<int>Fibonacci;
    int one = 0;
    int two = 1;
    int three = 0;
    int i = 0;
    while (i < 4000000){
        i += three;
        three = two + one; one = two; two = three;
        cout << three << ", ";
        Fibonacci.push_back(three);
        //all of the above is to produce the Fibonacci number sequence which starts with 1, 2 and    adds     the previous one to the next so on and so forth.
        //bellow is my attempt and taking those numbers and testing for evenness or oddness and then adding the even ones together for one single number.
    }
    cout << endl;
    //go through all points in the vector Fibonacci and execute code for each point
    for (i = 0; i <= 31; ++i)   
        if (Fibonacci.at(i) % 2 == 0)//is Fibonacci.at(i) even? 
            cout << Fibonacci.at(i) << endl;//how to get these numbers to add up to one single sum

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: What is your question ? (precisely)

Comment: What does this statement i += three;
 mean?

Comment: Which compiler is being used?  I cannot quickly find the post(s), but there are one or two compiler versions out there that struggle with the `std::vector::at` function.  Replace `Fibonacci.at(i)` with `Fibonacci[i]` and see what happens.

Answer (score 3):

Just do it by hand.  That is loop over the whole array and and keep track of the cumulative sum.

```
int accumulator = 0;  // Careful, this might Overflow if `int` is not big enough.
for (i = 0; i <= 31; i ++)  {
    int fib = Fibonacci.at(i);
    if(fib % 2)
        continue;
    cout << fib << endl;//how to get these numbers to add up to one single sum
    accumulator += fib;
}

// now do what you want with "accumulator".
```

Be careful about this big methematical series, they can explode really fast.  In your case I think the calulation will *just about* work with 32-bit integers.  Best to use 64-bit or even better, a propery BigNum class.

Comment: why `i+=2` ? He's looking for the even number in the fibonacci sequence

Comment: @user3018144 You are right.  I have corrected my example.  Although with a bit of care the OP could actually use `+= 3`, because every third number is even.

Comment: Thank you a lot, but why is it when I tried putting in int sum = Fibonacci.at(i); it would give me an error. Why is this different and what makes it work differently?

Comment: also, what does "continue" do in the program. What does it say.

Comment: @user3018144 Maybe you did not put `{` and `}` around the code in your `for`-loop. Then the varaible `i` is not visible after `cout << Fibonacci.at(i) << endl;`
Continue just skips the rest of a loop and goes on to the next iteration.

Comment: @maddin45 The `i` declaration is above the while loop.  So, its scope should be valid until the closing curly brace for `main`

Comment: You can also use `std::accumulate` which expresses your intent more clearly and avoids any iterator or index-variable mess. Use algorithms wherever you can.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the quick responses. Appreciate it.

Comment: Oh, whats the purpose of doing std::accumulate instead of the way it is now, what makes it more clear. I see this all over the place but since I do not fully understand it yet, its a little difficult to read code written like that

Comment: If I read `accumulate` I immediately know that this instruction tries to sum up a value using all elements of the container in some way or another. I don't have to read the entire loop body and it's impossible for an iteration to stop the accumulation using `return`. There is simply less to go wrong. Of course in this special case you will need a short lambda because the default implementation of `accumulate` will add all numbers, not only even ones.

Comment: @user3464478 I have added an answer for explaination. This chosen answer is perfectly fine, I'll just add it to give you and future readers a hint on how to use `accumulate`.

Comment: `continue` breaks out of the *current iteration* of the loop and goes onto the next one.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer by Adrian Ratnapala, I want to encourage you to use algorithms where possible. This expresses your intent clearly and avoids subtle bugs introduced by mis-using iterators, indexing variables and what have you.

```
const auto addIfEven = [](int a, int b){ return (b % 2) ? a : a + b; };

const auto result = accumulate(begin(Fibonacci), end(Fibonacci), 0, addIfEven);
```

Note that I used a lambda which is a C++11 feature. Not all compilers support this yet, but most modern ones do. You can always define a function instead of a lambda and you don't have to create a temporary function pointer like `addIfEven`, you can also pass the lambda directly to the algorithm.

If you have trouble understanding any of this, don't worry, I just want to point you into the "right" direction. The other answers are fine as well, it's just the kind of code which gets hard to maintain once you work in a team or have a large codebase.

Comment: thanks for the input, I definitely plan on learning this but as of now I just look at it in awe because I know I would of never came up with that in a million years but once I see it enough and figure out how it works I will definitely start writing code like this. Thanks.

Comment: This is always a matter of taste and personal oppinion and there was a lot of discussion going on when to use algorithms and when to write your own loop, but ever since lambdas were available it became much easier to use the algorithms. My coding style has changed considerably in the last few years and yours will probably as well. C++ has changed a lot since the first books and tutorials were written.

Comment: The trade-off is: use a nice named function that Expresses everytihng with a minimum of noise, vs. do it explicitly with no need for background knowledge.  In this case I think  @Excelcious is right to use the first approach -- at least for professional code where other readers should know enough C++.   The danger is people get carried away and write giant clever expression that hide more than they clear up.  Also in beginner code, the explicit approach is sometimes better.

Comment: The nice thing about this is that you can split the problem up into separate testable parts. `addIfEven` might not be the best example because it's very simple but still - I can verify that this function works correctly without worrying about any iterators or side-effects. The function doesn't have to know in what context it's being called, it has only one reponsibility.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're after...

but

```
int sum=0; // or long or double...
for (i = 0; i <= 31; ++i)   
    if (Fibonacci.at(i) % 2 == 0) {//is Fibonacci.at(i) even? 
        cout << Fibonacci.at(i) << endl;//how to get these numbers to add up to one single sum
        sum+=Fibonacci.at(i);
    }
    // whatever
}
```

Comment: I tried doing the sum += Fibonacci.at(i) but it told me that operator wasn't legal that it had to be vector<int> + int

Comment: Not sure what was the actual problem... but this code compiled fine for me `#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc,char **argv) {
   std::vector<int> a;
   a.push_back(10);
 
   int sum=0;
   sum += a.at(0);
   
   std::cout << sum << std::endl;
}`

Comment: See my comment above on the OP.  There are one or two compiler versions that do not handle the `std::vector::at` function correctly.  However, the `[]` operator does behave as expected.